# Using PDO to insert html form data into SQL table getting parse error

Tags: php

Im a bit confused on this subject, I have seen variances in answers I have found and looking for a bit more direction for my application. What I am trying to do is use a PDO method to take data from a form with multiple entries and insert the data into my table I created.

I think I have an understanding of the overall concept but what I would like to do or rather not do is have to create a variable ( $player1 = $_POST['player1'] or similar...) for every input field I have.

Is there a way in my sql statement I can use something like $_POST['player1'] to use the input from the form? I tried doing it as such below, but Im getting this error:

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) on line 19*

line 19 being the values line of the sql statment...

**html**

```
        <form method='post' action='phpfiles/Sqldata2.php'>
            Enter data in for team 1. <br>
            Enter Id: <input type='text' name='id1' maxlength='6'><br>
            Enter Teamname: <input type='text' name='team1' maxlength='30'><br>
            Enter city: <input type='text' name='city1' maxlength='30'><br>
            Enter Bestplayer: <input type='text' name='best1' maxlength='30'><br>
            Enter Year formed: <input type='number' name='year1' maxlength='4'><br>
            Enter website: <input type='text' name='website1' maxlength='40'><br>
            <br><br><br>

            <input type='submit' name='SQLdata' value='Submit Data'>                
        </form>
```

**php**

```
    <?php
     // server and database information
    $servername = " n/a  ";
    $username = "   n/a  ";
    $password = "   n/a  ";
    $dbname = "     n/a  ";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // begin the transaction
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            // our SQL statememtns
            $conn->exec("INSERT INTO teams (id, teamname, city, bestplayer, yearformed, website)
            VALUES ($_POST['id1'], $_POST['teamname1'], $_POST['city1'], $_POST['bestplayer1'], $_POST['yearformed1'], $_POST['website1'])");

            // commit the transaction
            $conn->commit();
            echo "New records created successfully";
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            // roll back the transaction if something failed
            $conn->rollback();
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

        $conn = null;
    }    
    ?>
```

The error im getting I believe is a syntax error such as that I need some more "" because my sql statment isnt a string? a little lost here and not sure if what Im trying to do is correct...

Comment: Use a prepared statement with parameter binding

Comment: You should definetly look in to the danger so SQL injection and use prepared statements and all that good stuff. But this is your immediate problem: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/5/10/0/arrays-in-strings

Answer (score 1):

You had some typos that had to do with quoting. Alos try to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. Finally check the `html name` attributes of your form with your `$_POST` names you use (`team1` or `$_POST['teamname1']`).

e.g.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO teams (id, teamname, city, bestplayer, yearformed, website) VALUES (:id1, :teamname1, :city1, :bestplayer1, :yearformed1, :website1)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
//Execute the query
$stmt->execute(array(':id1'=>$_POST['id1'], ':teamname1'=>$_POST['teamname1'], ':city1'=>$_POST['city1'], ':bestplayer1'=>$_POST['bestplayer1'], ':yearformed1'=>$_POST['yearformed1'], ':website1'=>$_POST['website1']));
```

Comment: lets say I have another set of data that needs to be inserted into the table along with this data.... essitianlly id2, teamname2, etc etc, do i just repeat the statment above and change values?

Comment: You can use the other insert way adding multiple rows: INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, 2), (47, 105), (402, 7), (102, 4);

Comment: INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9); (from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: Note that you have to bind all the values to avoid the SQL Injection.